# how to pass arraylist of "service" class in other classes in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service

here i am posting a part of myservice.java,i want to pass arraylist of  "service" class in other classes in android;so how to do that,i am very much naive to android.i want to set the value of **guestorderlist** arraylist in listview.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "service got started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");
    {
        {


            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_guests, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All custinfo: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // custinfo found
                    // Getting Array of custinfo
                    custinfo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CUSTINFO);

                    // looping through All custinfo
                    for (int i = 0; i < custinfo.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = custinfo.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String gname =  c.get(TAG_GNAME).toString();

                        // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_GNAME, gname);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        guestsorderList.add(map);

                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could get from your question was that you wish to pass ArrayList from one activity to other. If thats the question, you could pass ArrayList from one the parent activity to the called activity. Here is a sample:

```
ArrayList<TYPE> value = new ArrayList<TYPE>();
// populate the list
value.add(1.0);
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the target class, you may retrieve the list as follows:

```
// Call in in OnCreate()
// TYPE can be String, Double etc.
ArrayList<TYPE> list=(ArrayList<TYPE>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
```

Comment: if the desired class extends service then we cannot use getIntent()